# How to fix express.js error in Openshift?

Tags: node.js, express

I've installed express.js in specificed folder scoreboard, I'm trying to execute "npm start" in CLI, then I got error was:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.24
3 info using node@v0.10.25
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart application-name@0.0.1
6 info start application-name@0.0.1
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info application-name@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
9 error application-name@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
9 error Exit status 8
10 error Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
10 error This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
10 error not with npm itself.
10 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
10 error     node app.js
10 error You can get their info via:
10 error     npm owner ls application-name
10 error There is likely additional logging output above.
11 error System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
12 error command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "start"
13 error cwd /var/lib/openshift/54d99b5f5973ca0a11000120/app-root/runtime/repo/Scoreboard/scoreboard
14 error node -v v0.10.25
15 error npm -v 1.3.24
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

There content of app.js is:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
//app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080); 
app.set('ipaddr', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I had no idea how to fix it, I'm looking a solution how to run express in Openshift, Thanks!

Comment: what's in `package.json`?

Comment: Content of package.json is:

`{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.2.5",
    "jade": "*"
  }
}`

Comment: Apparently your app.js contains some errors. What is the output of running `node app.js` directly?

Comment: Actually, I solved an error, I decided to move from Openshift to Heroku which it's much better that I excepted. I cannot tell you more details about this error, I know... I've made a bounty here but it's too late because nobody cares here. If someone can resolve this without hint, I will add +1. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since this issue was opened, but I could deploy it successfully to Openshift.

Like Thimoty Gu said, there were some problems in your `app.js`. because some features you are using from Express are deprecated, what can impact to deploy an app to Openshift.

In Openshift I've had problems with very simple things, like setting the package.json with * instead of the right version of the dependency I wanted.

I did a few changes in your code without the routes file and it worked in my test. Basically, the result is:

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies" : {
    "express" : "4.9.5"   //it's important to set a version, instead of using *
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```js
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  //, routes = require('./routes')
  //, user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
//app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//app.use(express.favicon());
//app.use(express.logger('dev'));
//app.use(express.bodyParser());
//app.use(express.methodOverride());
//app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
//if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
//  app.use(express.errorHandler());
//}

app.get('/', function(req, res, err) {
 res.send("You have accessed page / (root)");
});

app.get('/users', function(req, res, err) {
 res.send("You have accessed page /users (users)");
});


var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080; 
var address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";

console.log("Port: " + port);
console.log("Address: " + address);

var server = app.listen(port, address, function() {
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

In summary, I just removed/commented your libraries that are not supported or are deprecated in Express. To use them now, you should include them from the new libraries that support them.

Hope it's somehow useful, even so long later.